# Smack API throws "Session establishment not offered by server" Exception

Tags: xmpp, smack

I'm trying to connect to the Vines XMPP server from Java using the Smack API. However, when I use the following connection code:

```
ConnectionConfiguration connectionConfiguration = new ConnectionConfiguration("localhost", 5222);
this.connection = new XMPPConnection(connectionConfiguration);
connection.connect();
connection.login(AUCTION_LOGIN, AUCTION_PASSWORD, AUCTION_RESOURCE);
```

I receive the following error message:

```
Caused by: Session establishment not offered by server: 
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.bindResourceAndEstablishSession(SASLAuthentication.java:456)
```

I understand the issue to be related to [sessions now being deprecated](https://community.igniterealtime.org/message/198886?sr=search&searchId=8df2617d-81f7-4ff7-8b47-d1abd87e5849&searchIndex=1#198886) from the XMPP protocol. I've been unsuccessful in finding a way to use the ConnectionConfiguration class and others to work around this problem.

Comment: Which version of Smack do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using an old, vulnerable Smack version (i.e. < 4.0.0).

The current stable Smack version does not throw such an exception, as it considers session binding to be option. It can even be completly disabled with [`setLegacySessionDisabled(true)`](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/ConnectionConfiguration.html#setLegacySessionDisabled(boolean)).

Comment: you are correct. I was using 3.*. I thought I'd grabbed the latest version from a site listing maven dependencies, but obviously not, and I can now connect. Thank you.

Comment: The artifact names were renamed with Smack 4. Essentially 'smack' became 'smack-core'.

Comment: Yeah, I picked up on that. I thought the connection was working, but since upgrading, I've received the exceptions stating missing certificate. I've attempted adding certificates, but I find the examples confusing dependant on the version of Smack being used. My current code is -> https://gist.github.com/paulspencerwilliams/f07104ecc51d14349799 Is there a definite example of using Smack 4.0.x with TLS / certificates?